# Load PHP Session through AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, infinite-scroll

I want to create an infinite scroll using an AJAX script I found on the web to load my PHP page when it reaches bottom.

The first page will use a session that will be printed by the php page which loads through ajax.

I've succeeded in doing so but I noticed that this doesn't work for the very first time, only after I refresh the page once, as if it can't load the session first time. I'm testing this using private sessions so I can simulate how it would look like for a new user.

So here I have index.php:

```
<script src="jquery-1.7-min.js"></script>
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['test1'] = '<br><br><br>content to be loaded';
?>
<div id="postswrapper">
    <div class="item">content</div>
    ...
    <div id="loadmoreajaxloader" style="display:none;"><center><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /></center></div>
</div>
---- footer content ----
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
    {
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
        url: "more-data.php",
        success: function(html)
        {
            if(html)
            {
                $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
            }else
            {
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
            }
        }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

And here is more-data.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    print_r ($_SESSION['test1']);
?>
```

I need to use session on the first page because I'm using it to load more content before the ajax kicks in. So removing the session is not an option.

It looks like the session doesn't load in "more-data.php" for the first time, only after I refresh the page. how can I fix this?

Comment: Hi Damien the `session_start()` goes to the top so before outputting the HTML

Comment: @AhmedDaou man, that was so silly, I've moved it before the <script> tag and it works from the first try. Thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ahmed said in the comments, the `session_start();` needed to go before the script tag and any other html for that matter. I tried it and it works without refresh. Thanks Ahmed for the solution!